# Is it possible to extend a non-static inner class in Java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

The reason I need the inner class to be non static is because I need the the inner class to have access to to a generic of the class which it is inside.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I speculate that you want to extends a non-static inner class from outside an enclosing instance, which is possible.

```
class Alpha
{
      class Beta ( ) { }
}

class Gamma extends Alpha . Beta
{
      // important to get the constructor right or else the whole thing fails
      Gamma ( Alpha alpha )
      {
             alpha . super ( ) ;
      }
}
```

You can also extend the inner class inside the original enclosing class

```
class OuterParent
{
     class InnerParent { }

     class InnerChild1 extends OuterParent { }
}
```

or extend the original enclosing class and extend the inner class in the child class

```
class OuterChild extends OuterParent
{
     class InnerChild2 extends OuterParent { }
}
```

Comment: It is possible. Crazy constructors. Probably shouldn't be done, but can be done.

Comment: Wow! I tried it and it did work, but you are right - it should not be done.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was with the constructor. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. It will have access to the members of the enclosing class.

Comment: Could you give an example?  If you have `Outer`, `Outer.Inner`, and `DerivedFromInner`, I don't see any way to access `Outer`'s members from `DerivedFromInner` through inheritance.

Comment: @Ryan Have you tried? The first two examples in emory's answer allow it.

Comment: @truthality Indeed, I have.  If you add `protected int a;` to Alpha and try to access it using `Alpha.this.a` in Gamma, you get 'No enclosing instance of the type Alpha is accessible in scope'.  Perhaps I'm accessing it incorrectly.

Comment: @Ryan You're right, it doesn't work that way, but if you save a reference to the instance of `Alpha` in `Gamma`, you do get access to the `Alpha` instance's `protected` members.

Comment: Right, but that's essentially composition, not inheritance.  There's no syntactic difference in the way you interact with the enclosing class; you don't inherit the implicit this pointer.